# JumpList in C# application (recent files)

Tags: c#, windows-7, taskbar

At the moment I am developing an application and want to add a Windows (7) JumpList. I followed several tutorials and studied documentation, but I can't figure out how to get the job done. In short: I want a recent list of last choosen files. So after closing the app, the user can easily open a recent file with my application. I already implemented some file association mechanism.

Is it possible to share some code/ tutorial how I can solve above problem?

Thank you in advance!

*I already tried the next few projects/ tutorials:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103913/How-to-Create-a-Custom-Jumplist-with-Custom-Events
- http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Windows-7-Jump-Lists
- http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.nl/2011/10/create-jumplist-using-c.html

*The code of Coding 4 Fun works, but I don't know how to develop a recent file list.

Comment: Why do you downvote my question? Please explain.

Comment: Probably, down-voters wanna see some code to elaborate on, otherwise it seems like working for free. Probably, not for sure.

Comment: I thought that the links to the various websites would be sufficient as I have tried that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23731/RecentFileList-a-WPF-MRU) article. Instead of showing result in WPF you need to show it in jumplist.

Why dont you try storing the recently opened file names in a database or an xml file and read it to set the jumplist. 
 For eg.

```
private void ReportUsage()

   {

       XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();

       myXml.Load(historyXml);

       string list = historyXml;

       jumpList.ClearAllUserTasks();

       foreach (XmlElement el in myXml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)

       {

           string s = el.GetAttribute("url");

           JumpListLink jll = new JumpListLink(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, s);

           jll.IconReference = new IconReference(Path.Combine("C:\\Program Files\\ACS Digital Media\\TOC WPF Browser\\Icon1.ico"), 0);

           jll.Arguments = el.GetAttribute("url");

           jumpList.AddUserTasks(jll);

       }

       jumpList.Refresh();

   }
```

Or a beginners solution will be retain all the file paths into a Queue of given maximum capacity and adding them at run-time into a menuItem. Sorry I didnt have time to write the whole code.

Comment: It would be a shame to reinvent the wheel. Microsoft already provides an implementation for storing recent files.

Comment: yep I agree. But I think he wants his jumplist to contain only particular files that his app can open instead of complete list where he will have to search for his assosiated file and then show only those files as jumplist items. Since creating his own file type's recent list will help him in adding more functionality related to his app also.

Comment: Thank you for this great solution! It is event better than a jumplist.

Comment: Great you liked my answer. Hope it helped you. And thnx for the bounty points.

Answer (score 2):

As it is described in [your second article](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Windows-7-Jump-Lists), your application must be registered as a handler for targeted file extension, otherwise the recent category for your Jumplist won't show up. You can find more details about file association registration [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#reg_verbs).

You can either manually register your application but you will need admin right so it is not recommended, or create a setup project for your application like described in the coding 4 fun article, or you can let the user associate the file extension.

Here is a sample which works for me under Windows Seven without registration, by just right clicking the text file I want to load and choosing "Open With" and browse to my application.

The sample require Windows API Code Pack

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var file = args != null && args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : string.Empty;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1(file));
    }

    public Form1()
        : this(string.Empty)
    {
    }

    public Form1(string file)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Open(file);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string message);

    private uint wmTBC;

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the window message for notification when the taskbar button is created.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The event args.</param>
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        wmTBC = RegisterWindowMessage("TaskbarButtonCreated");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the window message for notification of the taskbar button creation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">The window message.</param>
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == wmTBC)
        {
            OnTaskbarButtonCreated();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override this method to recieve notification when the taskbar button is created on Windows 7 machines and above.
    /// </summary>
    protected void OnTaskbarButtonCreated()
    {
        if (TaskbarManager.IsPlatformSupported)
        {
            jumpList = JumpList.CreateJumpList();
            jumpList.KnownCategoryToDisplay = JumpListKnownCategoryType.Recent;
            jumpList.Refresh();
        }
    }

    JumpList jumpList;

    private void openToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Open(ofd.FileName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Open(string file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) && File.Exists(file))
            {
                textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(file);

                if (TaskbarManager.IsPlatformSupported)
                {
                    jumpList.AddToRecent(file);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
        this.openToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.openToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 27);
        this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(796, 306);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // menuStrip1
        // 
        this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.openToolStripMenuItem});
        this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
        this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(820, 24);
        this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
        // 
        // openToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this.openToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.openToolStripMenuItem1});
        this.openToolStripMenuItem.Name = "openToolStripMenuItem";
        this.openToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
        this.openToolStripMenuItem.Text = "File";
        // 
        // openToolStripMenuItem1
        // 
        this.openToolStripMenuItem1.Name = "openToolStripMenuItem1";
        this.openToolStripMenuItem1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        this.openToolStripMenuItem1.Text = "Open";
        this.openToolStripMenuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.openToolStripMenuItem1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(820, 345);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
        this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem openToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem openToolStripMenuItem1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think it is not user friendly to manually associate files with an application. The solution of Jerin is better. Though one upvote for your answer.

Comment: No problem. Just to make things clear: the manual registration advice was more for testing purpose. The recommended way is definately to include this as a step in your installation process, as suggested in one of the link.